# A Suggestion for Improving Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, user-interface

It would be absolutely great to be able to add a feature in Stack Exchange such that users can export the questions they have asked or labeled as favorite to a single print-friendly document, which only contains the question asked as well as the comments and answers. I would be a great fan for this feature. Thanks.

Comment: this should be asked on meta.stackexchange, not here.

Comment: Thanks. Posted here http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230601/207804

Comment: For now, there is [TeXPrinter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texprinter/?source=directory)